# Read typing name from package.json in Monaco Editor

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, monaco-editor

I am having trouble adding custom type definitions to [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) with names starting with the `@` symbol. Here's an example that should illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
    typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"]
});

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    "export class Foo { }",
    "node_modules/@types/@my-module/sub/index.d.ts"
);

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(
        `import * as x from "@my-module/sub"`, 
        "typescript",
        new monaco.Uri("main.ts")
    )
});
```

This doesn't work because my custom module is called `@my-module/sub`. If in this example I replace the module name with `my-module/sub` then everything works as expected and I get Intellisense. Do you know if Monaco supports this scenario and if yes, then what would be the proper way to do it? Obviously changing my module name is not an option.

You can try this snippet in the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html).

Answer (score 6):

Managed to find a solution, just needed to remove the `typeRoots` compiler option and use `node_modules` prefix instead:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true
});

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    "export class Foo { }",
    "node_modules/@my-module/sub/index.d.ts"
);

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(
        `import * as x from "@my-module/sub"`, 
        "typescript",
        new monaco.Uri("main.ts")
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a module declaration so completion works on the module name

```js
const value = /* set from `myEditor.getModel()`: */ `import * as x from "@my-module/sub"

// Press ctrl-space after the .
new x.`;

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
});

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    // add the declare so intellisense learns about the module
    "declare module '@my-module/sub' { export class Foo { constructor(readonly hello: string) { } } }",
    // give the path so TS finds the definitions
    "node_modules/@my-module/sub/index.d.ts"
);

// Hover on each property to see its docs!
const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value,
    language: "typescript",
    automaticLayout: true,
});
```

[playground link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.45.0#XQAAAAKxAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw6CtMgARNaVuEbj-gjFqzGBtXS817XiZEX1ldCbGGnYLJJyAuJMHAsXWS4pstwBrUVCI-gQunsqE3gk5G4sF4yuxCrD5matVRPVh6uwlq91twpha-Sf2y4asM-G_1nTaraWmZYcUWQROzW6kDq8VX3KqfqNqONiLqF9cYhmOW5Gr4XcLclvpelfnVso9qJOUbT1VJnIACSwHTosrp4F84phWbcstDS6LGaP3XE5w9HVLDrD8Sv8pqZiqzrPCWlVyIBzZzxBpXYNXENeDkCEKBRCAv16L_u-9XOWp6UAsbM-Aem5xCFiDmQ9Q1IftVjggv2tLchFbkjeM8EqL8JBj3DZ1xReJqyF7hCC5bJn3K0W2-L-jZAVkSgn1DOkR1GSqDeZ7DH17rlzjGYaJT4AOvC7CIy048BmkczaCzvR8B7T9Ilk_6A2pZgVJ5oxDvV_clqxlWbm2sohuFfp8yS6l7gzKzT3oBuFKUcUQZZDcjTrE8vIj3ZZeiP_AoBqyN6DzkYAPAzZgA5IMwZXzleS4_qtJjHxj8s9jSlaM7zKWmZdrK3DuguHCw4c6YZOgvLyiK7CGOJT1A1DzXrVP0ff5z8xu84k9j9sWGONbWnivIT6lJPAHyPuni4zVcz0mnjvpAy_TQI08W04SSkzE8GwdtGPEWDjLxo8OvnP72zX5d)

Comment: How can Monaco find type definitions from a file? In a browser context there's no free file access.

Comment: @MikeLischke I preload the files via addExtraLib. So TS does know about the exports when I try to import.